# JSON Ampersand Convertion Causes Error

Tags: php, geocode, ampersand

When I try to parse my geocode links I get error because of amp; statement. Before i "json_decode" the string, i have a link named www.something.com/something?bla=bla&sensor=true but when i send it to the function as parameter its & character is being converted to `&amp;`. Links like

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Bekirdere,%20%C4%B0zmir&sensor=true
```

works fine but links like

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Bekkirdere,%20%C4%B0zmit&amp;sensor=true
```

doesn't give any results. (`&` is converted to `&amp;`)

How can i stop it getting converted?

My parser functions:

```
function get_url_contents($url) 
{
    $url = str_replace(' ', '%20', $url); 
    $crl = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);
    return $ret;
}

function __construct($url)
{
    $json = $this->get_url_contents($url);
    $this->_jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
}
```

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with JSON encoding/decoding.  Echo out your URL and "view source" on your page, and you will see that it is `&amp;` the whole time.

Comment: I did echo'ed it and yes it has "amp;" but when i visit the page with the link that has amp; it says "REQUEST_DENIED". However, if I replace "amp;" to "&" manually the link returns correct results.

Comment: Right, you shouldn't have `&amp;` in there.  It's showing up because somewhere in your code, you are encoding that URL with `htmlspecialchars()` or similar.  That would be proper if you were outputting HTML or XML, but since you are using the URL directly, you have the problem.  You should scrap this question and create a new one that has the code relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function is better than doing a str_replace and you should only encode those parts of the URL that are GET values; you should not encode the entire URL because as you point out, this also encodes the ampersands which separate the variables from one another.

You need to build the URL something like this:

```
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=';
$url .= urlencode('Bekirdere, Izmir');
$url .= '&sensor=true';
```

Then do your `curl` call as above.

I have tested the test script below, and it works:

```
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=';
$url .= urlencode('Bekirdere, Izmir');
$url .= '&sensor=true';

$crl = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$ret = curl_exec($crl);
curl_close($crl);

$returned_data = json_decode($ret, true);
var_dump($returned_data);
```

You'll need to fit this into your code structure or refactor your class to receive an `$address` parameter (e.g. 'Izmir, Turkey') instead of a complete URL (as it is now). That way, you'll be able to escape the address part before building the complete URL to pass to `curl`.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I don't know how encoding the address would help? In the end, this didn't help.

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood the question. Is your `curl` request failing because Google can't process the request URL when it has an escaped ampersand in it? By encoding only that part of the URL which needs to be encoded, `curl` will request the page without the escaped ampersand, thereby returning the JSON successfully (and it'll have results when you `json_decode()` it).

Comment: It used to work but now it doesn't. I think, it has something to do with encoding. Because when i manually visit the page (with replacing &amp; to & manually) pages return value.

Comment: Absolutely, that's the same for me and curl should work exactly the same way. If you encode only the postal address ("Bekirdere, Izmir"), the ampersand in the URL remains unencoded and, as a result, you will get back the JSON that  you're expecting. Have you tried it and found otherwise?

Comment: It didn't work. I only removed the line where str_replace occurs. Should i remove any other lines to prevent encoding?

Comment: Try the test script I just added to demonstrate that this works. You shouldn't be using `str_replace` at all. Instead you should use `urlencode()`, but _only_ for the postal address itself, not for the whole URL.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19058/discussion-between-aaron-pollock-and-gcx)